# When I create Instance on openstack (devstack) from webconsole , I am facing with error 500

Tags: openstack

When I was created a Instance from the DevStack CLI , server is up and running.But..
when I created an Instance  from web console , I am facing with error code 500.
Please kindly check my image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnJxE.png)description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me9oO.png) Pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your cinder service is not configured properly (or not configured at all). By default creating instances via horizon dashboard a volume is created. You can disable that for each instance in the tab where you select the image. If you create an instance via CLI it doesn't require a volume but an ephemeral disk is created. The horizon behavior can be changed to meet your requirements, so you could set the default to not create volumes when launching instances.